# Microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.tokencache threw an exception in Xamarin

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am getting this error while login to my xamarin application through ios simulators.It's working fine in emulator and uwp.Please help me on this.

Comment: Where is the relevant code?  Where are the details of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's worked after adding entitlements in Bundle sign in option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).